# How to merge many shape with the same name in different folders?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile, merge, union

I've many (hundreds) shape (3D points and 3D polygons) that have the same name, saved in different folders; and I've tried to merge them using batch with **Merge tool** in ArcGIS... but inexplicably ArcGis say that *cannot process file with the same name*! I'Now it's clear that I've too many files to rename them.

I've then used QGis and the process works, but lose the elevation information (Z) that I need.

I've seen other analogue questions but nothing directly usable. Some suggestions for a simply solution?

Comment: Have you got access to [FME](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/)? It can do point cloud combining and a lot of other handy GIS-related stuff. Not too complicated either.

Comment: No access to FME...

Comment: Are you willing to use Python?

Comment: Append don't work.  Aboute Python I'haven't a good kknowledge but I could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank everybody for the answers. At the end I've resolved using a simply process:

1. loaded all the same type of shapefile (eg: streets) in a geodatabase, selecting them with the OS function, searching for name.shp. During loading Arcgis auto-rename all the file with sequential name (eg: streets_04)
2. applied the merge tool
3. repeated process for the other types of shape (elevation, buildings, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

You can prefix all shapefiles with the folder that they are found within. A simple model as shown below can achieve this.

[image: The model to change shapefile names]

So your initial folder file structure may be this:

[image: Sample tree strucure]

After running this model all shapefile will be prefixed with the folder they they are found within (e.g. T2_myData.shp). Your data then has unique names so they will be valid input for your tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would...
1. Search the topmost folder for *.shp.
2. Drag and drop those shp files "only". (as your search may turn up the *.shp.xml files also).
3. use the [ETTools GeoWizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/) merge layers. (which is one of the [free functions](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear; You cannot merge point shapefiles with polygons shapefiles. Only the same geometry type can be merged.  I am sssuming that by merging, do you mean merging combining all the shapefiles into 1 shapefile not multiple features into a single multi-geometry feature.

You can create a new shapefile and load "Load Data..." all the shapefiles into it in ArcCatalog

OR

Add all the point shapefiles to map

Create a new destination point shapefile

Start Editing

Select all features in map

Copy

Paste all into destination

Select all features in destination shape

Save edits

NOTE: I sometimes order data ships in a similar folder hiararchy and it is a cumbersome manual process to add them into the "Load Features" dialog box one by one or even to add then to the map. I creates a simple ArcCatalog Add-In that seeeks all the folders with a given folder finds all shapefiles and copies them to a single location.  Unfortunately I my shapefiles all have different names and it skips duplicate names so It would have to be tweked for your purposes.  If you know how to write VB .NET code, I can share it.